# Prove that a function of the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ with subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ is injective

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Consider the set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ equipped with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions with $g \neq h$. Prove that there is $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $g(q) \neq h(q)$.

I am lost on how to write a proof for this question.

Comment: What do you know about the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : g(x) \neq h(x)\}$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $g \ne h$, so $\exists x \in \mathbb R$ such that $h(x) \ne g(x)$. Use continuity to show that there is an open neighbourhood $N_x$ of $x$ such that $h(y) \ne g(y) \ \forall y \in N_x$

Answer (score 1):

There is one point $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $g(x)\ne h(x)$.  Let $\varepsilon=|g(x)-h(x)|/2$.  Find $\delta>0$ small enough to work in the usual way for both $g$ and $h$.  Ask whether any rational numbers are between $x\pm\delta$, and what if one is?